# Composer dependencies require on Plesk

Tags: composer-php, plesk, plesk-onyx

Hello I have faced the issues that My Plesk suddenly show this message after login

> Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies
> require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0".

after that, I couldn't control my websites. Because no proceed to the next.
Does Plesk need something setting for resolution?
I can login via ssh on this Server now. If someone has solution for the issue. Please give me your advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share more details. Such an error won't happen "suddenly". Also, how is this related to Composer itself?

Comment: Hello Nico!
it was happened suddenly. According to this forum below, an extension of monitoring was updated on Plesk automatically. As a result, it occurred. I fixed the issue following the resolution on that page.

https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/8199905070610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from different forum. This issue was fixed!

```
plesk bin extension --disable monitoring
```